# Negative lookahead and negative lookbehind and multiple characters in PCRE

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have the following text:

```
aabbaa
aa bbc aa

bbg

aa           bbd   aa
```

I would like to find words that `starts with bb` that are `not between aa and aa` regardless of whitespaces preceding or following matching word using PCRE . In the above example only `bbg` should be matched.

I have created the following pattern:

```
(?<!aa)bb(\w)*(?!aa)
```

However only aabbaa is not matched and other do. I don't know how can I use `\s*` inside negative look ahead/behind to get desired result. It seems it cannot be simple done using:

```
(?<!aa\s*)bb(\w)*(?!\s*aa)
```

How can it be done?

Comment: Lookaheads must be zero-length, so quantifiers must be specified outside of it.

Comment: @Unihedron Yes I know it, but I didn't know how I can achieve this result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(*SKIP)(*F) Magic (No Lookaheads Needed)**

Use this:

```
(\baa\b).*?\1(*SKIP)(*F)|\bbb\w+\b
```

See the match in [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/5).

This problem is a classic case of the technique explained in this question to ["regex-match a pattern, excluding..."](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174/)

The left side of the alternation  `|` matches complete `aa ... aa` strings then deliberately fails, after which the engine skips to the next position in the string. The right side matches the `bb...` words you want, and we know they are the right ones because they were not matched by the expression on the left.

**Reference**

- [How to match (or replace) a pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174/)
- [Article about matching a pattern unless...](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html)

Comment: Why is there literally no mention of these features in the documentation...? I could've used that years ago!

Comment: At the moment I have no idea how it works but I'll try to understand it soon. Thank you

Comment: Marcin, the linked article explains it in great detail. It's a beautiful and simple technique. :)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Here's the [Perl doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Special-Backtracking-Control-Verbs) on the subject, there's also a bit in the `PCRE` doc but not as much detail. :)

Comment: Marcin, the key to understand is that there are two sides of the `|`... The left side is used to SKIP what you don't want, i.e. the `aa..aa` stuff... Then on the right you can freely match `bbetc` because any bad context has already been neutralised. It's simple and powerful. :)